# clickable panel header overlaps header buttons

Tags: css, angular

I have a panel component which has header with a title and buttons that are located in the right hand corner.

currently the downward arrow (chevron) toggles the expanding/minimising of the panels contents.

when I try to implement that the header is clickable to control the expanding/minimising of the panels contents, this also affects the "+" symbols button clickable event to also cause the panel to expand/minimise which is undesirable.

(click)="toggleShowHide()" shouldnt affect the "+" button

How do I have it that the "+" symbol is unaffected by the whole headers clickable event?
Bare in mind that other buttons may also join the "+" symbol in future

[image: My Panel header]

**dashboard.html**

```
<div style="width: 600px">
  <custom-panel heading="TABLE" enableShowHide="true">
    <span class="panel-tools" >
      <div class="input-group">
        <span  title="New content" (click)="addContent()">
          <i class="tools-plus fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
    //content
  </custom-panel>
</div>
```

**panel.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-custom">
  <div class="panel-heading" *ngIf="heading"  (click)="toggleShowHide()">
    {{heading}}

    <span *ngIf="enableShowHide" class="float-right panel-chevron" (click)="toggleShowHide()" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <i [hidden]="!showPanel" title="Hide" class="tools-plus fas fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i [hidden]="showPanel" title="Show" class="tools-plus fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>

    <span class="float-right">
      <ng-content select=".panel-tools"></ng-content>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body" [ngClass]="{'panel-scrolling': panelScrolling }" [hidden]="shouldHidePanel()">
    <div class="mb-3">
    </div>

    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

**panel.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.scss']
})
export class PanelComponent {
  @Input() heading: string;
  @Input() size: string;
  @Input() panelScrolling = false;
  @Input() enableShowHide = false;
  @Input() hideFirst = false;
  showPanel = true;

  toggleShowHide(): void {
    this.showPanel = !this.showPanel;
  }

  shouldHidePanel(): boolean {
    if (this.enableShowHide) {
      if (this.hideFirst) {
        this.showPanel = false;
        this.hideFirst = false;
      }

      return !this.showPanel;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

**panel.scss**

```
.panel-body {
  padding: 12px;
}

.panel-custom {
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: white;

  .panel-heading {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    @media (max-width: 1500px) {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to learn about "[event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)", so you added event listener on parent element and it automatically sets it for all child element (except elements which has own event handler and stopped propagation of parent events (links for example)).

So, you can just in event handler method use method "[stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)" in `event` object which is argument

Write in comments, if you need something, I will try to help you.

Comment: so to get this to work, I have had to add it at the start of my addContent() function in dashboard.ts. is there a way to have it only in the panel?

Comment: No, you have to set click event handler to '+' symbol element, and there use `stopPropagation`. (I don't see it in your code implicitly by the way).

Comment: plusIconClickHandler(e: Event): void {
    e.stopPropagation();
}

Something like this. stopPropagation stops parent event.

Comment: i added (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"  to dashboard.html, panel-tools span.
this fixed everything :D

Comment: that introduced a bug now that the chevron, downward arrow lost it's function, so i added the panel.html parent span of  <ng-content select=".panel-tools"></ng-content>

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the event from propagating further from origin is a good idea.

```html
<div class="panel-heading" *ngIf="heading" (click)="toggleShowHide($event)">
<span title="New content" (click)="addContent($event)">
```

```js
  toggleShowHide(event : any): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.showPanel = !this.showPanel;
  }

  addContent(event : any): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

Comment: the + symbol still toggles the show/hide when it shouldnt